# Build file '/home/makstkachyk/Jobs/RoadSignScan/node_modules/react-native-pytorch-core/android/build.gradle' line: 132

Tags: react-native, pytorch

**I'm trying to install PlayTorch on React Native, wrote everything as in the documentation, but I'm encountering this error.[I leave a note on the documentation I made](https://playtorch.dev/docs/next/tutorials/add-package/)**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/makstkachyk/Jobs/RoadSignScan/node_modules/react-native-pytorch-core/android/build.gradle' line: 132

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-pytorch-core'.
> Expected directory '/home/makstkachyk/Jobs/RoadSignScan/android/../node_modules/react-native/android' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where:
Build file '/home/makstkachyk/Jobs/RoadSignScan/node_modules/react-native-pytorch-core/android/build.gradle' line: 132 * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-pytorch-core'.
> Expected directory '/home/makstkachyk/Jobs/RoadSignScan/android/../node_modules/react-native/android' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files. * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 11s
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0. You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins. See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed.
```

[cannot find the file on the line 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOx4y.png)